# Validation rule for Multiselect picklist

Tags: picklist, validation

I have an issue with a Validation rule. A Picklist field abc if equals =Salesforce, then field xyz (multiselect picklist) becomes visible. It can't be left blank. I tried everything isblank with text, isnull, include, but it's not working. It's not giving an error if I am leaving xyz field blank.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the attempt(s) at this validation rule.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for a validation rule. Just make the multiselect picklist a dependent picklist on "abc", select the desired values for the dependency, and make the field required on the page layout. When an "abc" value is selected that isn't Salesforce, the multiselect picklist will be greyed out and have no options, and when Salesforce is selected, the UI will populate the values and make the field required.